# Google Style Toolbar CSS/HTML

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I am trying to recreate that Google-style toolbar on G-mail and a few other Google services.

[image]

I have tried doing this as both a formatted list and nested div elements in one container  but I have the same problem each time.

When you mouse over, the new 1px border moves all the other elements around and I have to apply stuff like:

```
left: -1px;
bottom: 1px;
```

Which is all well and good for the element currently :hover'd, all the rest move around and it looks ugly.

**So I guess my question is:**
Is there any way to display things such that a new 1px on :hover, will not alter the positioning, while still displaying these elements WITHOUT absolute positioning.

Obviously if the only avenue is absolute positioning where I have to put in pixel co-ordinations then sure, but there has to be a more elegant way.

Comment: Couldn't you put a border on the element on the non-hover state where the color matches the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do several thing to avoid the 1px border shifting things around on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZeikJT/tBmm2/

One solution is to add a transparent border (`border:1px solid transparent`) so that there is always a gap. This will work in pretty much all situations. It also allows you to then simply change the `border-color` on hover and not re-specify the border-width so you won't ever need to make changes in two places if you decide to change the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZeikJT/NkBwp/

Another solution is to add a margin or padding that then gets taken out on hover. This is a little trickier to get working properly but can work just as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I completely forgot you could use this kind of method. I guess I was looking for something too complicated and overlooked the simple stuff, nevertheless, I am grateful ^^

Comment: @ツ.jp No problem, sometimes when a problem seems difficult you go looking for a complex solution when the simple ones get overlooked ;)